# Mongo/Meteor cursor update event

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using Angular/Meteor to build a chat app.

**Question**

Is there a way to detect when there are changes to the MongoDB Cursor? Is there some event triggered when a row is added?

In my chat app, if I message another user, the new chat appears in the list (i.e. the MongoDB is updated), but I need to detect this update, so I can populate the new chat with the username, etc. If I refresh the page it is displayed correctly, but I need to be able to do this dynamically.

```
chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;
```

I am pretty new to Meteor, so don't quite understand it, but I do have the following:

```
      let promise: Promise<Mongo.Cursor<Chat>> = this.findChats();
      promise.then((data) => {
        this.chats = data;
        this.chats.observe({
          changed: (newChat, oldChat) => this.disposeChat(oldChat),
          removed: (chat) => this.disposeChat(chat)
        });
        this.addNewChatAndShowMessage();
      });
```

I am guessing I need to add something to the `observe` function. I would have thought `disposeChat` would be invoked when a new `chat` is added, but it is not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

```
        this.chats.observeChanges({
          added: function (id, object) {
            // This code runs when a new object "object" was added to collection.
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".